# Form validation for numbers

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have this code which has a form and a script that validates it if the inputted value is a number. The problem is when I click the submit/add button it will go directly to the addcontribution.php.

Additional i like also to add confirmation dialog. like"confirm adding (the amount)?" if yes it will proceed to addcontribution.php and if no it will go back to itself and reset the field.

```
<form form="CONTRIFORM" name='contribution' method="POST" Action="addcontribution.php" onSubmit="return formvalidation2();">
  <center>
    Amount:
    <input type="text" name="contriamnt" id="contriamnt" size="15" placeholder=" Amount"></br></br>
    <button id="searchbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">ADD</button></br>
  </center>
</form> 

<script>

function formvalidation2() {
    var amntDATA = document.registration.contriamnt;  
    if(allnumber(amntDATA)) {  
        if(ChangeText()) {
            if(new_tab()) {
            }
        }
    } 
    return false;  
}

function allnumber(amntDATA) {   
    var x = /^[0-9]+$/;  
    if(amntDATA.value.match(x)) {  
        return true;
    } else {  
        alert('Invalid Amount.');  
        return false;  
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is mismatch in form name

```
var amntDATA = document.contribution.contriamnt;
```

Comment: To further senk's answer, the code can't find the form `registration` which results to an error in the validation. Due to the code error, the form has been submitted. :)

Comment: that is correct but even after that it won't validate.

Comment: can you give some idea or code for the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<form form="CONTRIFORM" name='contribution' method="POST" Action="addcontribution.php" onSubmit="return formvalidation2();">
<center>
    Amount: <input type="text" name="contriamnt" id="contriamnt" size="15" placeholder=" Amount"></br></br>
    <button id="searchbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">ADD</button></br>
</center>
</form> 

<script>

function formvalidation2()  
{
var amntDATA = document.contribution.contriamnt;  
alert(amntDATA);
if(allnumber(amntDATA))  
{  
   alert("number");
   return true;
}else{
    alert("not a number");
    return false;
}

}

function allnumber(amntDATA)  
{   
var x = /^[0-9]+$/;  
if(amntDATA.value.match(x))  
{  
    return true;
}  
else  
{  
alert('Invalid Amount.');  
return false;  
}

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery instead of javascript.Code is simple

```
$("form").submit(function(){

    var value = $("#contriamnt").val();
    var x = /^[0-9]+$/;  
    if(value.match(x)) {  
        return true;
    } else {  
        alert('Invalid Amount.');  
        return false;  
    }


});
```

HTML:

```
<form form="CONTRIFORM" name='contribution' method="POST" Action="addcontribution.php" >
<center>
    Amount: <input type="text" name="contriamnt" id="contriamnt" size="15" placeholder=" Amount"></br></br>
    <button id="searchbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">ADD</button></br>
</center>
</form>
```

You can use jquery dialog plugin for pop up dialog 
        http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: I've tried it and it works well. I have some additional problem I edited/stated in my description.